# Why does ASP.NET refuse to recognize the namespace of a related project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC 2 project, which references several other projects in my solution.
In the C# code, all references work fine, but in the ASP.NET code things go awry - one of the referenced namespaces is not recognized.  I put in my Web.config file:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Project1"/>
    <add namespace="Project2"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

And as soon as I open the project, I get a crash screen with the message:

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Project2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I cannot see anything qualitatively different between `Project1` and `Project2`, yet the one's namespace is accepted as a valid while the other's isn't.  I have explicitly added references to `System.Data.Entity` as well; that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: add the C# code when it is working fine

Comment: @Nicholas - I don't understand - please could you clarify?

Comment: You posted 'I have a ASP.NET MVC 2 project, which references several other projects in my solution. In the C# code, all references work fine, but in the ASP.NET code things go awry'

Answer (score 2):

List of things that can be wrong can be found on : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304656

Short summary

- You might have misspelled the name of the type or namespace that you are trying to use.
- correct capitalization
- If the error is a reference to a namespace, you may not have the assembly where the namespace is located referenced in your project.
- If the error is a reference to a type, then you may not have the proper using directive, or you may have not fully qualified the name of the type.

You can also check root namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

That config specifies that the project's namespace should be included in all your pages (equivalent to putting a using statement in all your pages).

It doesn't however add a reference to the project - you probably need to add a reference to one of your other projects.  (Project2)

Comment: I do have a reference to Project2 - as evidenced by the fact that I can create a strongly-typed view based on an object in Project2 and the c# code referencing that project compiles fine.  But before I added those references into web.config, the project was running, and crashed when I opened that view because it couldn't find the namespace.

Comment: try changing it to <add namespace="Project2.NameSpace, Project2"/>  (namespace, assembly)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a reference to Project2?

Comment: I do have a reference to Project2 - as evidenced by the fact that I can create a strongly-typed view based on an object in Project2 and the c# code referencing that project compiles fine. But before I added those references into web.config, the project was running, and crashed when I opened that view because it couldn't find the namespace.

Comment: Perhaps there is a parent Namespace named after your solution i.e. MySolution.Project2?

Comment: I don't quite follow... where would such a setting be?  And if there were a parent namespace, why would the code be working for C# but not ASP?